# How to cache Spring Data JPA Projections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

I am running Spring Boot 1.5.1 with Spring Data JPA repositories. I have added a method to my User repository that makes use of JPA projections(UserProfile) which works great. I now wish to cache the results of that method in my Service layer which should return a result of type Page< UserProfile > as shown

The JPA Projection.

```
public interface UserProfile extends Serializable {

    long getId();

    @Value("#{target.firstname} #{target.othernames}")
    String getFullName();

    String getFirstname();

    String getOthernames();

    String getGender();

    String getEnabled();

    @Value("#{T(System).currentTimeMillis()-target.birthday.getTime()}")
    long getBirthday();

}
```

The User Entity.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6756059251848061768L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;        
    @Column
    private String firstname;       
    @Column
    private String othernames;
    @Column
    private String gender;
    @Column
    private String photoname;
    @Column
    private Date birthday;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    private Boolean enabled;
    @Column 
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String,String> phonenumbers = new HashMap<String,String>(0);

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>(0);

    //Omitted Getters and Setters 

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {...}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}


}
```

The User repository.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public Page<UserProfile> findAllUserProfilesBy(Pageable pageable);

}
```

The User service implementation.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository UserRepository;

    @Override
    @Cacheable("users")
    public Page<UserProfile> findAllUserProfiles(Pageable pageable) {
        //simulateSlowService();
        return UserRepository.findAllUserProfilesBy(pageable);
    }   

}
```

However I get the following exception when the service method gets called.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Class org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor does not implement Serializable or externalizable
```

How should I go about caching the result of the service method?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Caching the page seems wrong to me. Your `@Cacheable` has zero argument so it's going to use the `Pageable` argument to compute the key. That's certainly not do what you expect. Also your second level cache and this cache are completely disconnected so I'd rather cache at another level.

Comment: Thank you @StephaneNicoll for your reply, I very much appreciate the wisdom and I have a few more questions to ask regarding your reply. Since results of collections for getAll/findAll request methods  typically/often don't have arguments, I should manually assign key for reference in the key/value cache store, correct? something like `@Cacheable(cacheNames="users", key="'userspage-'+ #pageable.getPageNumber()")`... Also some enlightenment on how to align my second level cache with the spring cache. Unfortunately I still get the above exception

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The reason why you get this exception is because `Page` is not serializable and your cache provider (rightfully) stores a "copy" of your data rather than the reference (and, in order to do that, it attempts to serialize the object). You can't easily "align" the 2nd Level Cache with the application cache so I'd research other options.