# spring-data-redis with @Cachable & @Query gives a java.io.NotSerializableException on DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor

Tags: caching, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-cache

When using redis as a cache and `@Query` on a repository method, redis `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`, is unable to serialize a projection.

Put a github project with tests; https://github.com/varunmehta/spring-cache-error

**Actual Entity**

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  private Integer id;
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private String email;
  private String address1;
  private String address2;
  private String city;
  private String state;
  private String country;

  // ... setter/getter

}
```

**Concrete DTO;**

```
public class ConcreteIdKey implements Serializable {
  private Integer id;
  private String value;

  public ConcreteIdKey(Integer id, String value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

**Interface Projection**

```
public interface ProjectionIdKey extends Serializable {

  Integer getId();

  String getValue();

}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

  @Query("SELECT new com.github.varunmehta.model.ConcreteIdKey(u.id as id, concat (u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) as value) FROM User u")
  List<ConcreteIdKey> findsConcretesByProjectedColumns();

  @Query("SELECT u.id as id, concat (u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) as value FROM User u")
  List<ProjectionIdKey> findsProjectedByProjectedColumns();

  @Query("SELECT new com.github.varunmehta.model.ConcreteIdKey(u.id as id, concat (u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) as value) FROM User u")
  @Cacheable("concrete")
  List<ConcreteIdKey> findsCachedConcretesByProjectedColumns();

  @Query("SELECT u.id as id, concat (u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) as value FROM User u")
  @Cacheable("projected")
  List<ProjectionIdKey> findsCachedProjectedByProjectedColumns();

}
```

When calling `UserRepository.findsCachedProjectedByProjectedColumns`, I get the error;

**ERROR**

```
  at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:93)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$CacheValueAccessor.convertToBytesIfNecessary(RedisCache.java:471)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$BinaryRedisCacheElement.<init>(RedisCache.java:504)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:225)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:194)
  at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:85)
  at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:784)
  at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:417)
  at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
  at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.findsCachedProjectedByProjectedColumns(Unknown Source)
  at com.github.varunmehta.repos.UserRepositoryTests.testCachedProjected(UserRepositoryTests.java:51)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor
  at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:68)
  at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:35)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:91)
  ... 43 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
  at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:762)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
  at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:46)
  at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:63)
  ... 45 more
```

Also filed a spring-bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1160

Let me know if it is my error or a real bug.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970980/how-to-cache-spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: It is similar, but not a duplicate, also the answer on the above mentioned question about Page sounds wrong. Even if I move the call to an aggregation layer (like a service layer), I still get the same exception.

Check this; https://github.com/varunmehta/spring-cache-error

Comment: Projections are currently not serializable but maybe there's something we can do about it.

Comment: There's no answer in the link I gave. But the comment explains the rationale of the issue.