# HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize Interface-based Projections

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hazelcast, projection

I want to cache result of `Interface-based Projections`
but I got this error

> Caused by:
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException:
>   Failed to serialize 'java.util.ArrayList'

```
@Repository
    public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerRepository, Long> {       
        @Cacheable(value = "customer")
        @Query("select c.first_name as firstName from customer where customer_id in :customerId")
        List<NamesOnly> findByCustomerId( @Param("customerId") List<String> customerId);
    }

    public interface NamesOnly extends Serializable {

        String getCustomerFirstName();

    }
```

it seems extends `Serializable` not working

Comment: Does it work without `@Cacheable` ? `NamesOnly` has no fields

Comment: sure it works without `@Cacheable`

Comment: Ok, let me check deeper

Answer (score 1):

This is a Spring issue, buried in the depths is this:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor
```

Might be another occurrance of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287281/spring-data-redis-with-cachable-query-gives-a-java-io-notserializableexcepti)

As a workaround, you could change

```
List<NamesOnly> findByCustomerId( @Param("customerId") List<String> customerId);
```

to

```
List<String> findByCustomerId( @Param("customerId") List<String> customerId);
```

as your projection only returns a single column, `firstName`, which presumably is a string.

Without `@Cacheable` what you get back is a list (*serializable*) of proxy classes (*not serializable*).
With `@Cacheable` the list gets sent to the distributed store (Hazelcast) for caching, and this fails as the list is serializable but the list elements aren't.